# How to assign MySQL table rows to different variables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got MySQL table with only 3 columns. Data in that columns sorted by sub_id number like below:

```
sub_id | field_name | field_val
1 ------- carname -------ford
1 ------- driver ------- michael
1 ------- licence -------123
2 ------- carname -------bmw
2 ------- driver ------- robert
2 ------- licence -------321
```

For working with table i've got code below:

```
   $link = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
   mysql_select_db("xxx");
   mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8');
   mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
   $query = "select sub_id,field_name,field_val from wp_cformsdata WHERE sub_id IN ($ID)";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
```

It gave me set of rows by desired ID. I understand that is pretty uncomfortable to have such a messy table, but it created automatically by the plugin. **Question is how can i assign each row that i get to different variables? I want to use this variables to fill html document.** Sorry for bad english:)

Comment: Please take the time to learn the new `mysqli` or PDO interfaces for MySQL. You're using `mysql_query` and are exposing yourself to a potentially severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php) even in this short example where `$ID` is inserted without any obvious escaping.

Comment: @tadman $ID may not be a user input.

Comment: If it's not obviously escaped, you can't assume it is escaped. This is why placeholders are the best way to do it. You can't screw it up without your mistake being obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You're just going to have to iterate over all results, manually compare the field name and sub_id to something which you expect, then assign the result to a variable in a conditional.

Personally, I'd iterate over that and create an array of sub_id => fields, so something like

```
while($row = mysql_row($result))
    $users[$row['sub_id']][$row['field_name']] = $row['field_value']
```

The syntax is wrong since I can't remember the exact syntax for `mysql_*`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Please, can you give the right syntax. It seems to be what i need, but  i'm total newbie.

Comment: Just go and take the concept and look up the correct calls in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

"Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used." Right from the documentation, those methods you are using are deprecated.

Here is how you get each item, you have to loop since its a results, set.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $car_name = $row['carname'];
    $driver =  $row['driver'];
}
```

And so on..

Comment: The index or column name is as follows $row['this_is_the_database_field_name'];

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different variables. I suggest using `switch` in your PHP code:

```
$link = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
mysql_select_db("xxx");
mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$query = "select sub_id,field_name,field_val from wp_cformsdata WHERE sub_id IN ($ID)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    switch($row['field_name'])
    {
        case 'carname':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'driver':
            // do something else
            break;
        // add more "case" here
        default:
            // do the default action here
    }
}
```

Also, read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to help you choosing what to use instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Please note to the OP that `mysql_` functions are being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think you need something as simple as a loop to read the rows for your document.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
mysql_select_db("xxx");
mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$query = "select sub_id,field_name,field_val from wp_cformsdata WHERE sub_id IN ($ID)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<div> <?php echo $rows['sub_id'];?> </div>
<div> <?php echo $rows['field_name'];?> </div>
<div> <?php echo $rows['field_val'];?> </div>
<?
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

I hope this helps. You can use mysql_fetch_assoc() as well.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, thats not what i need.